# Alternative ways of generating QR/Aztec code in iOS 12

Tags: ios, qr-code, core-image, cifilter, ios12

It looks like Apple removed `CIAztecCodeGenerator/CIQRCodeGenerator` filter names from `CIFilter`. I can't find any trace in documentation but I can't find them when I do `CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)` in iOS 12 Beta (Xcode 10 Beta 2).

```
let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAztecCodeGenerator") // filter is nil
```

Anyone knows anything about that? 
And does anyone come up with a workaround/an idea to generate QR/Aztec codes in iOS 12?

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours with simulator, I just found out that `filter` is `nil` only in simulator. When I run my app on an iOS 12 Beta device, it works without any problem.
I hope anyone else won't spend hours with that issue.